# Having a tree structure on both sides of the Transfer component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I am using [antd's Transfer](https://ant.design/components/transfer/) component. Using the examples given in the documentation, I am able to create a tree transfer box that looks similar to:
[image]

Is there a way I could have a tree structure also on the right side? Currently, as I select `0-1-0` under `0-1`, it appears flat on the right side.

The code as also given in the [Sandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/7z4j4w5zk6), is given below:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';
import './index.css';
import { Transfer, Tree } from 'antd';

const { TreeNode } = Tree;

// Customize Table Transfer
const isChecked = (selectedKeys, eventKey) => {
    return selectedKeys.indexOf(eventKey) !== -1;
};

const generateTree = (treeNodes = [], checkedKeys = []) => {
    return treeNodes.map(({ children, ...props }) => (
        <TreeNode {...props} disabled={checkedKeys.includes(props.key)}>
        {generateTree(children, checkedKeys)}
        </TreeNode>
    ));
};

const TreeTransfer = ({ dataSource, targetKeys, ...restProps }) => {
    const transferDataSource = [];
    function flatten(list = []) {
        list.forEach(item => {
        transferDataSource.push(item);
        flatten(item.children);
        });
    }
    flatten(dataSource);

    return (
        <Transfer
        {...restProps}
        targetKeys={targetKeys}
        dataSource={transferDataSource}
        className="tree-transfer"
        render={item => item.title}
        showSelectAll={false}
        >
        {({ direction, onItemSelect, selectedKeys }) => {
            if (direction === 'left') {
            const checkedKeys = [...selectedKeys, ...targetKeys];
            return (
                <Tree
                blockNode
                checkable
                checkStrictly
                defaultExpandAll
                checkedKeys={checkedKeys}
                onCheck={(
                    _,
                    {
                    node: {
                        props: { eventKey },
                    },
                    },
                ) => {
                    onItemSelect(eventKey, !isChecked(checkedKeys, eventKey));
                }}
                onSelect={(
                    _,
                    {
                    node: {
                        props: { eventKey },
                    },
                    },
                ) => {
                    onItemSelect(eventKey, !isChecked(checkedKeys, eventKey));
                }}
                >
                {generateTree(dataSource, targetKeys)}
                </Tree>
            );
            }
        }}
        </Transfer>
    );
};

const treeData = [
    { key: '0-0', title: '0-0' },
    {
        key: '0-1',
        title: '0-1',
        children: [{ key: '0-1-0', title: '0-1-0' }, { key: '0-1-1', title: '0-1-1' }],
    },
    { key: '0-2', title: '0-3' },
];

class App extends React.Component {
    state = {
        targetKeys: [],
    };

    onChange = targetKeys => {
        console.log('Target Keys:', targetKeys);
        this.setState({ targetKeys });
    };

    render() {
        const { targetKeys } = this.state;
        return (
        <div>
            <TreeTransfer dataSource={treeData} targetKeys={targetKeys} onChange={this.onChange} />
        </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

The way I want to transfer is depicted in the images below.

- I want to be able to transfer the children
- When a child is transferred the left table should have the remaining children under it parent and the right table should have the transferred children under it parent name.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What do you except on selecting the tree `Head`? That all it's children selected and you can transfer it as a Tree? What happens when a tree `Child` selected? Only the child transferred?

Comment: @DennisVash Children will never be parents. So a parent can have 5 children but children will never become parents. When a child is selected and moved, I want to move that child and display it under the parent.

Comment: @DennisVash Also is there a way to do this with a `table` instead of a `tree`? I have a working example here : https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-mendeleev-hhcw5?fontsize=14

Comment: @DennisVash The only problem that I am facing is that I am unable to move the children when working with the tree.

Comment: Yes, you can do it with a table and with a tree, the problem that I don't understand the desired behavior. You should elaborate in your question, what happens when the **child** transfers? What do you see on the screen, give a clarify example and I'll help you with the table and with the tree

Comment: Give example what happens when you transfer `0-1`, does ALL tree transfers? When you click on on `0-1-0`, what happens to `0-1-1`? Does `0-1` transfers with it and what stays on the left table?

Comment: @DennisVash I have updated my question. Does it make it clear?

Comment: Much better, can you transfer the whole tree by clicking the root?

Comment: @DennisVash Yes, we could transfer the complete tree i.e the parent and all its children.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out this [example](https://zey36.codesandbox.io/) where:

- `TransferTree` is an example of checking nodes and showing the tree path.
- `AntdTreeTransfer` an example for `Transfer` component with tree path on transfer.

[image]

```js
export const renderTreeNodes = data =>
  data.map(item =>
    item.children ? (
      <Tree.TreeNode title={item.title} key={item.key} dataRef={item}>
        {renderTreeNodes(item.children)}
      </Tree.TreeNode>
    ) : (
      <Tree.TreeNode {...item} dataRef={item} />
    )
  );

export const filterTree = (keys, halfKeys, rootNode) =>
  rootNode
    ? rootNode
        .filter(node => keys.includes(node.key) || halfKeys.includes(node.key))
        .map(nodeRoot => ({
          ...nodeRoot,
          children: filterTree(keys, halfKeys, nodeRoot.children)
        }))
    : [];

export default function TreeTransfer() {
  const [checkedNodes, setCheckedNodes] = useState([]);

  const onCheck = (selectedKeys, info) => {
    const filteredTree = filterTree(selectedKeys, info.halfCheckedKeys, data);
    setCheckedNodes(filteredTree);
  };

  return (
    <FlexBox>
      <Row type="flex" gutter={20}>
        <Col>
          <Card>
            <Tree checkable defaultExpandAll onCheck={onCheck}>
              {renderTreeNodes(data)}
            </Tree>
          </Card>
        </Col>
        <Col>
          <Card>
            <Tree checkable defaultExpandAll>
              {renderTreeNodes(checkedNodes)}
            </Tree>
          </Card>
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </FlexBox>
  );
}

export default function AntdTreeTransfer() {
  const [leftCheckedKeys, setLeftCheckedKeys] = useState([]);
  const [checkedNodes, setCheckedNodes] = useState([]);
  const [targetNodes, setTargetNodes] = useState([]);

  return (
    <FlexBox>
      <Transfer
        operations={['', 'Clear']}
        onChange={(_, direction) => {
          setLeftCheckedKeys([]);

          direction === 'right'
            ? setTargetNodes(checkedNodes)
            : setTargetNodes([]);
        }}
        style={{ width: '50vh' }}
      >
        {({ direction, onItemSelect, selectedKeys }) =>
          direction === 'left' ? (
            <Tree
              showLine
              blockNode
              checkable
              defaultExpandAll
              checkedKeys={leftCheckedKeys}
              onCheck={(selectedKeys, info) => {
                setLeftCheckedKeys(selectedKeys);
                const filteredTree = filterTree(
                  selectedKeys,
                  info.halfCheckedKeys,
                  data
                );
                setCheckedNodes(filteredTree);

                const eventKey = info.node.props.eventKey;
                onItemSelect(eventKey, selectedKeys.includes(eventKey));
              }}
            >
              {renderTreeNodes(data)}
            </Tree>
          ) : (
            <Tree
              autoExpandParent
              blockNode
              checkable
              onCheck={(selectedKeys, info) => {
                const eventKey = info.node.props.eventKey;
                onItemSelect(eventKey, selectedKeys.includes(eventKey));
              }}
            >
              {renderTreeNodes(targetNodes)}
            </Tree>
          )
        }
      </Transfer>
    </FlexBox>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit Q-56680158-TreeTransfer]

Comment: Thank you. I have created my own transfer component. Would you like to see it? I joined 2 tables to create a similar effect.

Comment: Im guessing its the component from the other question

Comment: I recently asked a question, where I created a custom select box with antd. Is there a better way to display custom values just after a selection is made : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56954681/controlling-the-way-selected-value-inside-the-select-box-looks-is-there-a-way/56954946#56954946 I was able to do it and have also posted an answer but it appears that I get a warning `index.js:1437 Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `value` supplied to `Option`.`I make a selection. Would you know a better way?

Comment: I added an answer hope it helps