# Controlling the way selected value inside the select box looks : Is there a way to render the selected item separately?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I am working with the [antd' select box](https://ant.design/components/select/). I tried to customise the content inside `Option` which holds the regular `text` with some JSX. It looks as follows:

[image]

Here is also the small demo I prepared on sandbox:

[image: Edit epic-hofstadter-tswpz]

Since I have customised the content inside the `Option`, the moment I make a choice with the Select Box, it gets shown as:

[image]

As you could see, the select box tries to show everything. Is there a way I could control how the select box looks just after the choice is made with the select box? I just want the name to be displayed after the selection is made. For example, `product-1` must be displayed when the first option is selected.

For easier reference, I am also posting the code here:

```
    import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import "./index.css";
import { Select } from "antd";

const { Option } = Select;

const data = [
  {
    productName: "product-1",
    productExternalId: "DT01A",
    productionExternalId: "PL-DT01A",
    quantity: "700 kg"
  },
  {
    productName: "product-2",
    productExternalId: "DT01A",
    productionExternalId: "PL-DT01A",
    quantity: "700 kg"
  },
  {
    productName: "product-3",
    productExternalId: "DT01A",
    productionExternalId: "PL-DT01A",
    quantity: "700 kg"
  }
];

const ProductSelectBox = React.memo(props => {
  const { details } = props;

  function onSelect(value, option) {
    console.log(value, "..", option);
  }

  function customizedOption({
    productName,
    productExternalId,
    productionExternalId,
    quantity
  }) {
    return (
      <Option
        className="product-select-box-item"
        key={productName}
        value={productName}
      >
        <div className="d-flex flex-column">
          <div className="d-flex" style={{ marginBottom: "0.2rem" }}>
            <div className="mr-auto-1 font-weight-bold">{productName}</div>

            <div className="uppercase">{productionExternalId}</div>
          </div>

          <div className="d-flex" style={{ marginBottom: "0.01rem" }}>
            <div className="mr-auto-1 uppercase">{productExternalId}</div>
            <div>{quantity}</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </Option>
    );
  }

  return (
    <Select
      // labelInValue
      // defaultValue={{ key: "product-3", label: "product-3" }}
      className="product-select-box"
      size="large"
      onSelect={onSelect}
    >
      {details.map(product => customizedOption(product))}
    </Select>
  );
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    <ProductSelectBox details={data} />
  </div>,
  document.getElementById("container")
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve this with the antd's `value` property on `Select` box. Here is the demo I updated in sandbox:

[image: Edit epic-hofstadter-tswpz]

For easier reference, I am also posting the code here:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import "./index.css";
import { Select } from "antd";

const { Option } = Select;

const data = [
  {
    productName: "product-1",
    productExternalId: "DT01A",
    productionExternalId: "PL-DT01A",
    quantity: "700 kg"
  },
  {
    productName: "product-2",
    productExternalId: "DT02A",
    productionExternalId: "PL-DT02A",
    quantity: "702 kg"
  },
  {
    productName: "product-3",
    productExternalId: "DT03A",
    productionExternalId: "PL-DT03A",
    quantity: "703 kg"
  }
];

const ProductSelectBox = React.memo(props => {
  const { details } = props;
  let { defaultSelected } = props;

  const productMap = {};
  details.forEach(product => {
    productMap[product.productName] = product;
  });

  const [selectedProduct, selectProduct] = useState(defaultSelected);

  function onSelect(value) {
    selectProduct(value);
  }

  function customizedDisplayOnSelection(productName) {
    if (productMap[productName]) {
      const productExternalId = productMap[productName]["productExternalId"];
      return (
        <span className="font-weight-medium">
          {productExternalId} - {productName}
        </span>
      );
    } else {
      return "";
    }
  }

  function getSelectedMeta() {
    if (productMap[selectedProduct]) {
      return (
        <span className="font-weight-medium">
          (
          <span className="uppercase">
            production id: {productMap[selectedProduct]["productionExternalId"]}
          </span>
          <span style={{ marginLeft: "0.75rem" }}>
            Batch Size: {productMap[selectedProduct]["quantity"]}
          </span>
          )
        </span>
      );
    } else {
      return "";
    }
  }

  function customizedOption({
    productName,
    productExternalId,
    productionExternalId,
    quantity
  }) {
    return (
      <Option
        className="product-select-box-item"
        key={productName}
        value={productName}
      >
        <div className="d-flex flex-column">
          <div className="d-flex" style={{ marginBottom: "0.2rem" }}>
            <div className="mr-auto-1 font-weight-bold">{productName}</div>

            <div className="uppercase">{productionExternalId}</div>
          </div>

          <div className="d-flex" style={{ marginBottom: "0.01rem" }}>
            <div className="mr-auto-1 uppercase">{productExternalId}</div>
            <div>{quantity}</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </Option>
    );
  }

  return (
    <div className="d-flex flex-row">
      <Select
        className="product-select-box auto-flex"
        size="large"
        value={customizedDisplayOnSelection(selectedProduct)}
        onSelect={onSelect}
      >
        {details.map(product => customizedOption(product))}
      </Select>
      <div className="d-flex align-items-center auto-flex">
        {getSelectedMeta()}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    <ProductSelectBox details={data} defaultSelected="" />
  </div>,
  document.getElementById("container")
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Referring from [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56680158/having-a-tree-structure-on-both-sides-of-the-transfer-component/56858970?noredirect=1#comment100484326_56858970):

To fix your warnings, on `customizedDisplayOnSelection` and `getSelectedMeta` you should return a `ReactNode` and not a `string`, for example you can just return `null` which is a valid `ReactNode` or not return anything.

```
function customizedDisplayOnSelection(productName) {
  if (productMap[productName]) {
  ...
  }
  // or
  else {
    return null;
  }
}
```

Furthermore, you can take advantage of `&&` short-circuit.

```
const customizedDisplayOnSelection = productName =>
  productMap[productName] && (
    <span className="font-weight-medium">
      {productMap[productName].productExternalId} -{productName}
    </span>
  );
```

Check fixed example:

[image: Edit Q-56954681-FixWarning]

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to separate `label` and the actual `value`? For example, currently I set the value to `ReactNode`. But when I query the field (using validateFields or getFieldsValue), I would want the result to be `productExternalId`. Is there a way to do this?